# Laravel 6 Without Blade

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have this Advanced Programming assignment building an e-commerce website. I am using Laravel 6. However, the assignment states that the server must be independent of the client, therefore I cannot use blade. Instead all the client-side must only comprise HTML5, CSS and Javascript. How can I go about linking my backend with my frontend? I have tried searching online for an answer but since I'm very new to Laravel, I don't quite understand how to go about this. Could you guys point me the right direction?

Comment: Honestly I have 2 msgs here : 1 .  An assignment is a no-no in SO.. I hope students get that the assignments are meant.. for your skills development. period. 2. On the other hand.. , you had asked the question nicely.. I'll give credit to that.. /(^_^) but to ask something here.. without some sharing of all the efforts tried/researched/screenshot/code/method done.. it'll be a bit hard for others to assist.. try [_this_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. you may edit and improve this question. ( :

Comment: okay thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hey @TajC, you'd want to use Vue or some other front end framework. You can check my profile and reach out if you need some help getting that started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your assignment is asking is to create a restless **backend** API and **frontend** to consume it. When you are going to access your site you will be contacting the frontend and then the frontend is going to retrieve what info it needs from the backend and display them to you. Usually, the backend and frontend run on different servers (eg a **php server** for the backend and **node.js** for the frontend) but this isn't always the case.

Basically he wants two separate projects the backend and the frontend.

The frontend can be created by using just **html-css-javascript** or by using **react.js**, **vue.js** or any other library for building ui's.

In both cases you will use ajax call to get the info from your backend (in your case the laravel app) to the frontend.

- Check this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/building-and-consuming-a-restful-api-in-laravel-php) for building a backend api with laravel.
- Check this [tutorial](https://www.codemag.com/article/1601031) for consuming api in html.
- Check this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/10/consume-api-data-http-vuejs-web-application/) for consuming api with vue.js

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: @TajC .. if this answer statisfy your need, you may 'tick' this answer to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. ( :